# Failed to connect to mydb.database.windows.net:1433 in 15000ms (Microsoft Azure SQL Database)

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am able to retrieve data from `Microsoft Azure SQL Database` using below code: -

```
const sql = require("mssql");

var config = {
  user: "user_name",
  password: "Pass@1234",
  server: "mydb.database.windows.net",
  database: "db_name",
  options: {
    enableArithAbort: true,
  },
  stream: true,
};

module.exports = function getQueryResult(query) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    sql.connect(config).then((pool) => {
      pool.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) rej(err);
        res(result);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

I am using `getQueryResult` function to get the data from database.

Everything is going perfect accept the thing that the below errors occurs in between.

- `Failed to connect to mydb.database.windows.net:1433 in 15000ms (Microsoft Azure SQL Database)`
- `ConnectionError: Failed to connect to mydb.database.windows.net:1433 read ECONNRESET`
- `ConnectionError: Failed to connect to mydb.database.windows.net:1433 socket hang up`

I know this question has been asked before. But I have tried all the solutions. None of the solution was specifically for `Microsoft Azure SQL Database` so I thought might be there is some problem in database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you query that database from SSMS on your machine? If yes try to execute that code from your machine and tell me if it worked

Comment: You need `encrypt: true` in your config.options when talking to Azure, but that should fail immediately. Seems like there's a firewall somewhere between your Node server and Azure.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning If I pass `encrypt: true` then it doesn't make any difference. But if I pass `encrypt: false` then nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit different from mine, my `options` is enclosed in double quotes.  You also can [download my sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/node-mssql), it works for me, I have test it.

**Tips:**

You need set the rule of `Firewalls`. Make sure your local or webapp can access dbserver.

[image]

**My code:**

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    user: 'username',
    password: 'pwd',
    server: '***sqlserver.database.windows.net', // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
    database: 'yourdb',
    "options": {
        "encrypt": true,
        "enableArithAbort": true
    }
}

const poolPromise = new sql.ConnectionPool(config)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err))

module.exports = {
  sql, poolPromise
}
```

Comment: I am not getting error in connection. Everything is working perfectly but 5% of the request fails. I have tried your code but still no difference.